# Increase/Decrease a field in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to count (and sum up) different (physical) items and input those counts in a spreadsheet. Is there a way to increase (or decrease) an integer in a field in OpenOffice Calc? Mouse or keyboard input.

Either a shortcut+macro combination or something along the lines of these (fictive) arrows:

[image: Increase/Decrease Field]

i.e. pressing up would increase the field to value 43

In fact I would be happy for any suggestion for an open programme that would digitalize such input and produce some sort of csv or similar output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via `View` - `Toolbars` - `Form Controls` get the toolbar `Form Controls` visible.

There you have `Spin Button` control (see tooltips).

Insert this on the sheet by clicking it and pull the size of it with the mouse. Pull it longer than width.

Right click the control and select `Control...` from the context menu.

On the `Data` tab set the `Linked cell` to `A3` for example.

Now switch the design mode to off by clicking the corresponding button at the toolbar `Form Controls` (see tooltips).

[image]